# Расширения Chrome - ранний запуск runtime.onStartup для фоновой страницы с persistent = false

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension

В манифесте для background указан параметр persistent = false, что означает, что фоновая страница может быть закрыта браузером и запущена заново при надобности в ней.

В чем состоит моя проблема: Есть переменная, которую мне нужно сохранять между перезапусками фоновой страницы и браузера. С этим проблем нет, можно использовал localStorage, ну или chrome.storage.sync/local.

Но мне необходимо при первом запуске браузера установить эту переменную в определенное значение. Это должно быть сделано **строго перед** тем, как пойдут выполняться основные действия.
Т.е. по сути есть такой код:

```
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
  localStorage.setItem("variable", 0);
});
//Основные действия:
var my_var = localStorage.getItem("variable");
my_var += 3;
localStorage.setItem("variable", my_var);
```

Но ведь мы вешаем обработчик события, а затем начинаем обрабатывать код дальше. В итоге есть шанс, что chrome.runtime.onStartup сработает сразу же, но это именно шанс, а не гарантия.

При этом основные действия будут выполняться каждый раз, когда фоновая страница будет загружаться в память (из-за persistent = false)

Comment: А вы пробовали основные действия повесить на событие? Например на тот-же runtime.onStartup. Или после установки переменной генерировать событие, и подписаться на него?

Comment: В том то и дело, что основные события мне нужно выполнять при каждом перезапуске фоновой страницы (напоминаю, persistent=false), а не только при первом запуске.
Не совсем понял про "подписаться".
На англоязычном stackoverflow мне предложили сразу же после обработчика onStartup вызвать alarm с основными действиями, мол коллбэки выполняются по-очереди. Это правда, что для коллбэков выделяется всего 1 поток?

Comment: да, поток всего один. подробнее можно почитать тут: http://javascript.ru/tutorial/events/timing
думаю, что на англоязычном stackoverflow вам дали верный совет.